# R function or package for carrying out maximum likelihood techniques in random effect models

Tags: optimization, r

I am applying `optim()` function in R to obtain maximum likelihood estimates of the fixed effects and random effects in a model with bivariate random effects. The code works well but it is very slow in executing the line of code involving the `optim()` function. I would like to know if there is/ are any specialized optimization function(s)/ package(s) in R for maximizing likelihoods in random effect models, instead of the general purpose optimization function `optim()`.

Comment: You don’t care if the functions suggested are written in R or just R-callable and available to you, right?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest trying [Bound Optimization By Quadratic Approximation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/nloptr/versions/1.2.1/topics/bobyqa) which is sometimes used for random-effect modeling.